# Vue router not recognizing child component of View

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

**The router does not load the components inside my view...**

this is the structure:

the view: *(test works, finMain does not)*

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <finMain></finMain>
    <p>test</p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  name: 'FinView',
  component: {
    finMain: () => import("../components/finance/finMain"),
  }
};
</script>
```

the router:

```
export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/financial",
            name: "financial",
            component: () => import("@/views/finView")
        }

    ],
});
```

if i put `component: () => import("../components/finance/finMain")` in my router it works... but not if I wrap the component inside the View..

**This is the error i get:**

```
Unknown custom element: <finMain> - did you register the component correctly? 
For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <FinView>
       <VApp>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's just misspelling, change `component: {` to `components: {`.